# (in html) Breaking up a png, applying filter effects, and scaling moving the pieces

Tags: javascript, image, animation, canvas, effects

For a current project I am trying to break up a png, apply filter effects, and then scale and move the pieces.

Jus picture an explosion but in reverse:)
I know I should use the Canvas element. 
And that using a third party javascript library would make most sense.

Can anyone recommend any Canvas tutorials that do something similar?
Which 3rd party .js libraries(if any) would you use to achieve this?

Any help most appreciated!

Comment: You may use several `div`s with css `transform` and `background-position`.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by @kirilloid is valid, but if you want to do complex visual effects on your pngs, you should use the `canvas` element.

Here is an amazing tutorial for `canvas`: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/

Comment: Thanks Rémi! Will check it out